# Python 3 disappeared from computer - MacOS

Tags: python, homebrew

I am on OS Mojave and just used homebrew to install `geos` and `proj` and python3 disappeared. I had two versions and now I only have the 2.7 version. I did `brew install python3` and it says its already installed but not linked, I then did `brew link python` as it suggested but it returned an `Error: Could not symlink Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers Target /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers is a symlink belonging to python@2.`.

How can I go back to having both versions?. I am not 100% installing `geos` and `proj` was what caused it but I used python3 3 days ago.  I have also installed `phantomjs` via homebrew since the last time I used python3.

I need to have both versions of python installed. What would be the appropriate way of handling this since I seem to have all the files still on my computer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$ type python` to see where it points to. Use `brew info` command to list the info on installed python.

```
$ brew info python
python: stable 3.7.6 (bottled), HEAD
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5 (4,032 files, 61.8MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2019-11-04 at 22:34:01
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/python.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: gdbm ✔, openssl@1.1 ✔, readline ✔, sqlite ✔, xz ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
Python has been installed as
  /usr/local/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin

If you need Homebrew's Python 2.7 run
  brew install python@2

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages

See: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python
```

See the lines under `Caveats`

> `Python has been installed as`
>   `/usr/local/bin/python3`

that's your python3 alias path. you can safely symlink `python` to point to it in `~/.bash_profile`

```
$ echo 'alias python=/usr/local/bin/python' > ~/.bash_profile
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
###########################
# you'll probably see these kind of lines before your alias
###########################

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/Cellar:$PATH
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python
```

restart your terminal for it to take effect

```
$ type python
python is aliased to `python3'
$ python
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov  1 2019, 02:16:32) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: `brew info` says that python3 is in the directory you stated but when I go to `/usr/local/bin`  there is no folder `python3` only `python2`.

Comment: did you take a look at `/usr/local/Cellar/python/`?

Comment: There it says python3.7.6. How would I go about restoring it to have both versions?

Comment: what about `type python` output?

Comment: Says `/usr/local/bin/python`, where I only have python2 versions

Comment: and what about `type python3`? let's [continue to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207034/brew-python3)

Answer (score 1):

use anaconda python distribution which better for python.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I don't wanna screw up the python versions I have with all their packages and I don't know if this would do that (or how to do it).

Answer (score 0):

Install Virtual Environment so you can use many and different versions of Python.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I don't wanna screw up the python versions I have with all their packages and I don't know if this would do that (or how to do it).